# How to get the date clicked when calendar allows multiple date selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

I have a calendar in which user can select multiple dates  at a time and enter same event for all the selected dates in the database.  When the calendar is rendered, all the dates with which event is associated are highlighted. I want to know which specific date user clicked but since some dates are already highlighted, I'm having trouble finding which specific date user clicked.

If I use Calendar.SelectedDate, and since multiple dates are selected, this property contains the first date in the range which is not what I want.  If I use Calendar.SelectedDates collection, I get all the highlighted dates and not the date I clicked.

The reason I want to know which specific date user clicked is because I want to display event details associated with that date if any. Is this possible?

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DateTime dt in hs)
    {
        if (!Calendar1.SelectedDates.Contains(dt))
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);                     
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(dt);
        }
    } 
    hs.Clear();

    DateTime selDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        DateTime calDate = (DateTime)row["caldate"];

        if (calDate == selDate)
        {
            txtDate.Text = row["caldate"].ToString();
            txtDate.ReadOnly = false;
            txtDate.Attributes.Clear();
            txtDate.Visible = true;
            hdnDate.Value = calDate.ToShortDateString();                        
            txtSchedule.Text = row["schedule"].ToString().Trim();
            hdnRID.Value = row["id"].ToString();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            hdnDate.Value = "";
            txtSchedule.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the following lines from the code above, I get the clicked date. But these lines allow to select multiple dates. I just don't understand how and why,  when I include these lines, I do not get clicked date correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    foreach (DateTime dt in hs)
    {
        if (!Calendar1.SelectedDates.Contains(dt))
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);                     
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(dt);
        }
    } 
    hs.Clear();
```

Joe

Comment: how are you "highlighting" these dates? are you using the SelectedDates collection to basically multi-select separate days of the month? Or are you using a client script to style the calendar to highlight it?

Comment: my initial thought is that if you are using the Calendar1.SelectedDates collection to highlight the calendar and then trying to select a new date and add it to the SelectedDates collection... The Calendar1.SelectedDate will always equal the first selected Date on the calendar.